# How do I check whether a std::function is bound to a specific object's member function?

Tags: c++11, callback, function-pointers

I'm looking for a way of checking whether a std::function pointer is bound to a member function of a particular object. I'm aware that std::function itself has no '==' operator. I have however come across the std::function::target method which should be able, in principle, to give me the address of the function to which the pointer is pointing. My starting point was therefore this:

```
bool MyClass::isThePointerSetToMyMethod(std::function<void (const char*, string)> const& candidate)
{
    // Create a pointer to the local reportFileError function using the same syntax that we did in the constructor:
    std::function<void (const char *, string)> localFn = std::bind(&MyClass::theLocalMember, this, 
                                                                   std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    // Find the target
    auto ptr1 = localFn.target< std::function<void (const char *, string)> >();

    // Find the target of the candidate 
    auto ptr2 = candidate.target< std::function<void (const char *, string)> >();

    // Compare the two pointers to see whether they actually point to the same function:
    if (!ptr1 || !ptr2) return false;
    if (*ptr1 == *ptr2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This doesn't work, and the reason is that the values of 'ptr1' and 'ptr2' are always returned as null. According to [the documentation for the std::function::target method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target), this must be because the type that I've specified for the target is not correct.

If I look at what target_type(localFn) actually is (using Visual C++ 2013), it's a bit frightening:

```
class std::_Bind<1,void,struct std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall MyClass::*)(char const *, string),void,class MyClass,char const *,string>,class MyClass * const,class std::_Ph<1> &,class std::_Ph<2> &>
```

Nevertheless, target_type(candidate) gives the same result, so I thought I'd try a typedef:

```
bool MyClass::isThePointerSetToMyMethod(std::function<void (const char*, string)> const& candidate)
{
    typedef class std::_Bind<1,void,struct std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall MyClass::*)(char const *, string),void,class MyClass,char const *,string>,class MyClass * const,class std::_Ph<1> &,class std::_Ph<2> &> wally;

    // Create a pointer to the local reportFileError function using the same syntax that we did in the constructor:
    std::function<void (const char *, string)> localFn = std::bind(&MyClass::theLocalMember, this, 
                                                                   std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    // Find the target
    auto ptr1 = localFn.target< wally >();

    // Find the target of the candidate 
    auto ptr2 = candidate.target< wally >();

    // Compare the two pointers to see whether they actually point to the same function:
    if (!ptr1 || !ptr2) return false;
    if (*ptr1 == *ptr2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Alas this gets me no further; the values of ptr1 and ptr2 are still null.

So for now I've run out of ideas. Is there anyone reading this who knows either:

(1) The appropriate form for a typedef for a std::function pointer to the member function of a class, or

(2) A better way to achieve my ultimate objective, which is to tell whether a std::function pointer is pointing to a particular object's member function or whether it isn't?

[Background, in case anyone is interested: the reason I'm doing this is that I have a callback table where different callbacks are set to different functions depending on the state that the system is in; this makes state control very simple, as it means that in a given context I can call a given callback and know that the actions taken by the function I've called will be appropriate for the current state, without having to know anything about what that state actually is. Usually, when an object is instantiated which will change the system state, it takes control of the relevant callback(s) and binds them to whatever local member functions are appropriate for whatever state it's in. Under these circumstances, however, the object's destructor ought to return the callbacks to their *status quo ante* so that they are not left pointing to nothing.

Very rarely, an object may bind the callbacks to its member functions in its constructor, but before its destructor is called another object may take control of the same callbacks itself, and re-bind them to member functions of its own. If this happens, then the first object's destructor needs to be able to recognise that this has happened, and exit without affecting the callbacks' assignment to the second object's methods. The obvious way to do this is for the destructor to be able to check whether the callbacks are still assigned to its own methods or not, and if they are not then to leave well alone.]

Comment: You are not really meant to use the return type of `std::bind`. This honestly sounds like an XY problem. How about slightly restructuring your callback table to store a pointer to the object as well?

Comment: Why not make the callback table more intelligent and allow it to apply and unapply the changes to the callbacks it stores?

Comment: @T.C., yes, even I think it sounds like an XY problem which is why I've said a bit more about X than I would in a typical Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Pradhan,that's actually a rather good idea; at the moment my callback table is a bunch of std::functions held in a C-style struct, but making it into a C++ class with the methods necessary for it to do its own bookkeeping might be a good way forward. Would you care to post it as an answer, so I that I have the option of accepting it? The other workaround I'd been thinking of was to give each function an optional third parameter which, if present, would return a UUID to identify it unambiguously. I think yours sounds neater, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flesh out the callback table into a class which manages the table. All modifications to the table should be done through this class's interface. Internally, you would maintain a stack-like structure which lets you undo the changes done to the callback table. Barebones interface would look something like:

```
class CallbackTable
{
public:
bool ApplyChanges(...)
{
//Push the old values of the entries that would be changed here into your change-tracker stack and modify the table
}

bool UnApplyChanges(...)
{
//Pop the change-tracker stack and restore the table to the state it was in before the most recent change was applied.
}
};
```